# Switch case problems in c language

Tags: c

it is my first time using switch..case and I need to do a program where the user choose an operator, select 2 numbers and then it shows the result, but when I do that it goes for all the options and I don't know why

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  char op;
  double first, second;
  printf("Enter an operator (+, -, *, /): ");
  scanf("%c", &op);
  printf("Enter two operands: ");
  scanf("%lf %lf", &first, &second);

  switch (op) {
    case '+':
      printf("%.1lf + %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first + second);
    case '-':
      printf("%.1lf - %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first - second);
    case '*':
      printf("%.1lf * %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first * second);
    case '/':
      printf("%.1lf / %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first / second);
    default:
      printf("Error! operator is not correct");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did the class you are taking or the book you are reading or the online tutorial you are using not say to put a `break;` statement in each case unless you want them to fall through?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `case` labels in a `switch` statement are exactly that: labels.  They do not subdivide the body of the statement into smaller blocks; rather, they simply mark different places (different *statements*, in fact) to which control can branch.  The behavior you describe is the natural result.  If you don't do anything to prevent it, control flow that branched into the `switch` body at one label continues uninterrupted through other labels.

To break out of a `switch` at any point, use a `break` statement.  It is usual to put a `break` before each `case` label and before the `default` label, if any.  Example:

```
  switch (op) {
    case '+':
      printf("%.1lf + %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first + second);
      break;
    case '-':
      printf("%.1lf - %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first - second);
      break;
    case '*':
      printf("%.1lf * %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first * second);
      break;
    case '/':
      printf("%.1lf / %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first / second);
      break;
    default:
      printf("Error! operator is not correct");
  }
```

Some sources even advocate putting a `break` at the end of the last case, though that has no functional effect.

Occasionally, however, the programmer intentionally allows fall-through behavior.  Here's a not-altogether-implausible prototype example:

```
switch (c) {
    case 'a':
        // fall through
    case 'e':
        // fall through
    case 'i':
        // fall through
    case 'o':
        // fall through
    case 'u':
        handle_vowel(c);
        break;
    default:
        handle_consonant(c);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the `break` in the finish of all your cases

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `break` after the statement in each case. Here is the main syntax of a switch statement in C and C++, but it can be applied to other programming languages too.

```c
switch(expression) { 
 case value1:    
     statement_1; 
     break;
 case value2:    
    statement_2; 
    break;
  ...
 case value_n:    
     statement_n; 
     break;
 default:     
     default statement;
}
```

The `break` keyword tells the program to stop testing the switch cases after the `statement` is completed.

Comment: To improve this answer, you should elaborate on what the `break` does and why it's important. It is _not_ a required part of switch statement syntax, and there are numerous cases where leaving it out is actually useful.